# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: expected [3] but found [3]

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, assert

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\srajendran\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://qaclickacademy.com/practice.php");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement Radio = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='radio1']"));
    Radio.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    WebElement Radio2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='radio2']"));
    Radio2.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@class='radioButton']")).size(), "3");
    System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@class='radioButton']")).size());
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    WebElement Checkb1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='option1']"));
    Checkb1.click();


    WebElement Checkb2= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='option2']"));
    Checkb2.click();

   System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).size());
```

Answer (score 8):

Hi size() returns integer and you are comparing with string

> You can use the size() method of java. util. ArrayList to find the
>   length or size of ArrayList in Java. The size() method returns an
>   integer equal to a number of elements present in the array list. 
>   https://www.java67.com/2016/07/how-to-find-length-size-of-arraylist-in-java.html

So the  fix would be to change "3" to 3:

```
Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@class='radioButton']")).size(), 3);
```